Entering File Paths in Inkscape Import Dialog
I want to paste file paths into the Import file dialog, rather than navigating through folders.
I have thousands of images with nearly identical names, and often I have selected an image for a particular purpose already, and want to use the same image again in Inkscape. Is there any way to just paste in the file path that I already have copied to my clipboard? Or at least to type it in?
Details:

Inkscape 1.3.2
OSX, Sonoma 14.4.1

What happens:

I copy the file path of an image to the system clipboard, eg from the "Copy 'foo.jpg' as Pathname" menu item.
I open the Import dialog in Inkscape.
I expect there to be a text field where I can paste the path, but there is none. There is only a file browser and a "breadcrumb"-style navigation control at the top.
Attempting to paste the file path with CMD+V makes a text field with a magnifying glass appear, and Inkscape attempts to search for the file path as if it is a file name in the current folder, never finding anything.


Consider asking superuser.com rather than here for such non-programming questions.

This issue isn't specifically linked with Inkscape but with the widget toolkit used. It is most likely it is GTK.
If it is GTK indeed, you can type CTRL-L to obtain a text box instead of the button-rendered path and can paste a path there.
https://winaero.com/gtk-open-save-file-dialog-keyboard-shortcuts/
